# Use Manipulate where there are fixed parameters and one varies in an interval

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

I manually give values to $R$ and I get different graphs similar to plant leaves. I would like to do it continuously, with Manipulate, in the interval $ 1.07\leq R \leq 1.71 $. Whether the leaf is horizontally or vertically, it doesn't matter.

```
(*Constants:*)
m = 73;
jN = 150;
jd = 45;
k = 2.5;
(*R varies: 1.07 \[LessEqual] R \[LessEqual] 1.71, for example for R \
= 1.07:*)
R = 1.07; 
y = Table[(1.1)^m ((j - 1)/(jN - 1)), {j, jN}];
x1tojd = Table[(1 + 0.1/R (1 - ((jd - j)/(jd - 1))^k))^m, {j, jd}];
xjdtoN = Table[(1 + 0.1/R (1 - ((j - jd)/(jN - jd))^k))^
m, {j, jd + 1, jN}];
x = Join[x1tojd, xjdtoN];
f = ListLinePlot[Transpose[Flatten /@ {y, # x}] & /@ {1, -1}, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
f1 = Show[
MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[90 Degree]] &, 
f, {1}], PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False]
```

Comment: How about:    Manipulate[    **your stuff**    , {R, 0.7, 1.71}]

Comment: Change `R = 1.07` to `R = .; Manipulate[` and `Axes -> False]` to `Axes -> False],
 {{R, 1.5}, 1.07, 1.71, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`.